# Php - T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php, forms

i've got a simple php form submit script.
Email are not sent because error log shows:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"<div style='display: block; w' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/...
```

At the end of the submit i have an echo, which is probably the cause of this problem:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="Name: $name \nSubject: $subject \nMessage: $message";
$recipient = "email@domain.com";
$subject = "Contact";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo
"<body style='margin: 0;'>" .
    "<div style='display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat; text-align: center; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;'>" .
        "<span style='font-size: 14px; color: #fff; display: block; padding-top: 30px;'>Message sent</span>" . 
        "<a href='index.php' style='text-decoration: none; background: #333; color: #fff; padding: 10px 14px; display: block; margin: 30px auto; width: 100px;'>Home</a>" . 
    "</div>" .
"</body>";
?>
```

I've searched around SO and most common issue is missing ' or . somewhere, but i looked and looked and can't find anything missing. Any help appriciated, thanks :)

Edit: Updated the full code.

Comment: Your above code works fine and shows me a button "Home", you need to  provide the code prior this line.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, I tested it (FF 26.0). Something else is causing this. If you're including this from another file, then check that. @dd5

Comment: Yep i tought so. I'll check other files and try to find a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this instead of what you have used after form submission:

```
echo
'<body style="margin: 0;">' .
    '<div style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat; text-align: center; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;"> '.
        '<span style="font-size: 14px; color: #fff; display: block; padding-top: 30px;">Message sent</span>' . 
        '<a href="index.php" style="text-decoration: none; background: #333; color: #fff; padding: 10px 14px; display: block; margin: 30px auto; width: 100px;">Home</a>' . 
    '</div>' .
'</body>';
```

Comment: Difference is in single quotes instead of double?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it so because you have no variables in the html-code:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $formcontent="Name: $name \nSubject: $subject \nMessage: $message";
    $recipient = "email@domain.com";
    $subject = "Contact";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
?>
<body style="margin:0;">
    <div style="display:block; width:100%; height:100%; background:url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat; text-align:center; font-family:Arial, Helvetica;">
        <span style="font-size:14px; color:#fff; display:block; padding-top:30px;">Message sent</span>
        <a href="index.php" style="text-decoration:none; background:#333; color:#fff; padding:10px 14px; display:block; margin:30px auto; width:100px;">Home</a> 
    </div>
</body>
```